# Need to retrieve data from a certain API in Json (C#)

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

I need to retrieve the name of every product from an API to a listbox in C# (Visual Studio) and I've managed to login sucessfully into the API. I was able to retrieve the data of each product serialized but when I try to deserialize it the result for each product comes like this: 'app1.Form1+Data'. How can I retrieve the name of each product correctly?

**Code:**

```
public class Data
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
}


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
    string url = reqlbl.Text;
    WebClient c = new WebClient();
    String userName = "user";
    String passWord = "pass";
    string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" + passWord));
    c.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + credentials;
    var json = c.DownloadString(url + i.ToString());
    Data result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
    listBox1.Items.Add(result);

    }

}
```

**Note:** The variable 'i' represents a product. There are 20 products in total.

**Here's an API example of product 1:**

{"1":{"id":1,"name":"Product1"}}

Comment: Shoult it be `{"Data":{"id":1,"name":"Product1"}}`?

Comment: I don't think so, the number 1 is representing the object/product number.

Comment: That json doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You probably need to add another class `Product` that has an `int id` and `Data item` as members, and then Deserialize to `product` instead of `Data`

Comment: @Achilles While I agree with the structure, a _key_ of name "1" seems pretty odd.

Comment: I thought that's what he means by: `the number 1 is representing the object/product number.`

Comment: `"app1.Form1+Data"` is the string returned by `Data.ToString()`.  You need to either override `Data.ToString()` add a specific member (e.g. `name`) to your list box.  (To correctly deserialize the JSON the answer by @TheGeneral looks correct.)

Comment: @Achilles I've tried that and the result comes out exactly the same as with the Data class: 'app1.Form1+Product'

Comment: @dbc I've tried to specify with result.name but the program just crashes.

Comment: @jpcode - that's likely because `result.name` is null.  You need to deserialize it correctly then add the name to the list box.

Comment: @Achilles Yes it does. I guess it is a Dictionary Key. It is just a weird (imho) way to represent it in json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The json is basically a dictionary, ie assuming it can return more than 1 product or something similar, or maybe its just lazily built api, who knows

**Exmaple**

```
var str = "{\"1\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Product1\"}}";
var dataDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(str);

foreach (var data in dataDict.Values)
    Console.WriteLine(data.id + ", " + data.name);
```

**Output**

```
1, Product1
```

---

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vz5KFq)